# Take screenshot in Unity3D with no lags

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, screen, screenshot

I have tried each of variants: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/ScreenCapture
Afterall, simple Application.Capturescreenshot(...) is the least laggy.

Please, tell me, How I can take screenshots without ANY lags? 
Lots of games on Android has thiis feature, so it's not impossible.

Comment: You could save the screenshot in another thread instead of saving it in a coroutine which is executed on the main thread thus introducing lag into your application.

Comment: @RCYR Capturescreenshot can only be called from the main thread.

Comment: what the hell's that command for sort of changing the framerate while you make screenshot videos? there was a question on it here lately..

Comment: Check out this repo: https://github.com/keijiro/AsyncCaptureTest . It use the asynchronous GPU readback API (introduced in Unity 2018.1) to capture renders without blocking the main thread. The developer of it works at Unity Japan.

Answer (score 9):

The **cause** of **lag** while taking picture is when you try to perform all steps at the same time **without** **waiting** after each step. To fix this, you **perform** one action and wait for **many** frames then perform the next action then **wait** again. And if you decide to **save** the picture during game-play, use **Thread** to save the picture.  `EncodeToPNG()` is another **problem** but I will talk about **another** solution for it later on.

The code below is good if you want to take screen shot then display it right away while game is running.
It will take picture right way then take about 1.5 seconds to save the file.

```
 IEnumerator screenShotCoroutine()
{
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/DrukaloScreenshot.png";

    Texture2D screenImage = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height);

    //Get Image from screen
    screenImage.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), 0, 0);

    //Wait for a long time
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        yield return null;
    }

    screenImage.Apply();

    //Wait for a long time
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        yield return null;
    }

    //Convert to png(Expensive)
    byte[] imageBytes = screenImage.EncodeToPNG();

    //Wait for a long time
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        yield return null;
    }

    //Create new thread then save image to file
    new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        File.WriteAllBytes(path, imageBytes);
    }).Start();
}
```

If you want to take the picture and you are **not** required to display the image right away, you can save the picture as **raw** `Texture2D`, then when you want to access/load/display the picture later on, you can **read** it from **file** then convert it to **PNG** later on. The reason for this is that `EncodeToPNG()` is very **expensive** so if you don't need the picture right away, there is no need to convert it to png. You can do that **only** when you actually **need** it as **png**. So now we can just save it as "**.t2D**" then load it after and convert the loaded image to "**.png**".

Save as Texture2D "**.t2D**"

```
IEnumerator screenShotCoroutine()
    {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/DrukaloScreenshot.t2D";

        Texture2D screenImage = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height);

        //Get Picture
        screenImage.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), 0, 0);

        //Wait for a long time
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            yield return null;
        }

        screenImage.Apply();

        //Wait for a long time
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            yield return null;
        }

        byte[] rawData = screenImage.GetRawTextureData();

        //Wait for a long time
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            yield return null;
        }

        //Create new thread then save image
        new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            File.WriteAllBytes(path, rawData);
        }).Start();
    }
```

Then when you actually need the image, load Texture2D "**.t2D**" and then covert it to "**.png**" followed by deleting the old "**.t2D**".

```
IEnumerator screenShotCoroutine()
{
    string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/DrukaloScreenshot.t2D";
    string newPath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/DrukaloScreenshot.png";

    Texture2D screenImage = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height);

    byte[] rawData = null;

    //Create new thread then Load image
    new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        rawData = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    }).Start();

    //Wait for a long time
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        yield return null;
    }

    //Put loaded bytes to Texture2D 
    screenImage.LoadRawTextureData(rawData);

    //Wait for a long time
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        yield return null;
    }

    screenImage.Apply();

    //Wait for a long time
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        yield return null;
    }

    //convert to png
    byte[] pngByte = screenImage.EncodeToPNG();

    //Wait for a long time
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        yield return null;
    }

    //Do whatever you want with the png file(display to screen or save as png)


    //Create new thread and Save the new png file, then Delete Old image(DrukaloScreenshot.t2D)
    new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        File.WriteAllBytes(newPath, pngByte); //Save the new png file(DrukaloScreenshot.png)
        File.Delete(path); //Delete old file (DrukaloScreenshot.t2D)
    }).Start();
}
```

Comment: I used your code and the same lag appears when I make screenimage during the gameplay. Lag is a little bit less noticeble like with Application.Capturescreenshot(...) Thanks, anyway. It's better but just a lttle bit

Comment: You mean my solution is 20% better than Application.Capturescreenshot(...) or Application.Capturescreenshot(...) is better than my solution?

Comment: Here how it goes: Firstly I tested on Xiaomi Redmi Note 2, and your solution was 20%better than Application.Capturescreenshot(...) andI wrote you the answer, than I tested on another phone, which is a little bit weaker than Note 2, and there your suggestion is much worse than Application.Capturescreenshot(...), it frethes a game for 0,7 second or so.

Comment: Well I dont know what to tell you. I tested it with Windows and used the profiler to reduce the slowdown as much as I could. Test it on iphone too. It should make a big difference because there are many android devices out there and the one that didn't do good is probably because it is a low end device.

Comment: Firstly was processor Mediatec X10 than Snapdragon 615.   615 is not low end processor, it's mid range segment. Thank you for your code suggestion,though.

Comment: i wonder if you tried this without the loops that do nothing but kill time?

Comment: @ina Yes,it can be done without those loops. This answer was provided when I was still new to Unity but it seems to be working well. I will update this post this weekend with much more better way. Check back on btw Saturday and Sunday

Comment: @Programmer any updates? I think, I've read all your post about taking screenshot, but I still didn't achieve desired performance.

Comment: Don't forget to destroy that textured2d at the end so that you prevent memory leaking.

Answer (score 3):

`Application.CaptureScreenshot()` is slow in general, a faster way is to use a `Texture2D` and read all the pixels on the screen on it using `ReadPixels()` function than you can encode and save the texture to the hard drive.

This is an example of this method:

```
Texture2D screenShot = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height);
screenShot.ReadPixels(new Rect(0,0,Screen.width,Screen.height),0,0);
screenShot.Apply();
byte[] bytes = tex.EncodeToPNG();
Object.Destroy(tex);
File.WriteAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "/../myScreenShot.png", bytes);
```

For a full reference you can use Unity scripting reference page [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.html).

Comment: `ReadPixels()` is very slow, because it will trigger a GPU flush which means waiting for all remaining commands in the current command buffer to execute

Comment: @Aray so what is the alternative?

Comment: @pookie unfortunately I don't. there is a project made by udacity and nvidia. they probably have done it somehow https://github.com/udacity/self-driving-car-sim

Comment: @Aray thanks, I checked.  They are using the exact same technique as I. See 1_SelfDrivingCar/scripts/camera helper.cs in their code.