# Allocating 5MB for a single variable within a Unity script

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, memory

*TL;DR below*

---

Hi,
I'm trying to make an in-game screen, whose purpose is to show the contents of another window running on the computer (under Windows). For that matter, I had to get my hands dirty and play with that good ol' Windows legacy API, the one with external references and everything. After a couple days of struggle, I was able to make it work! The only problem is that Unity doesn't seem to support it...
I already asked this on Unity answers, but had no answers.

---

I have a `WindowOperation` class which wraps all of the API calls into static methods, and also performs a few basic tasks. One of them consists in capturing the screen pixels and saving them in a `System.Drawing.Bitmap`:

```
public static Bitmap CaptureApplication(string procName)
{
    // ...
    var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    // ...

    return bmp;
}
```

Unity fails declaring `bmp` and outputs the following message in the console:

```
ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor (Int32 width, Int32 height, PixelFormat format)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Drawing.Bitmap:.ctor (int,int,System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat)
[More info about the stack trace, which leads to the declaration of bmp in the above code]
```

- According to MSDN and other threads on SO, such exceptions are thrown when .NET is unable to allocate a single block of contiguous memory as big as requested.
- Since I didn't have such problems when I tested my code outside of Unity, my best guess is that *(correct me if I'm wrong)* Unity sandboxes the execution of the script and somehow doesn't allow the allocation of the memory `bmp` needs.
- My screen dimension is 1600*900, and pixel depth is 3 bytes ( `PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb` ), so the amount of memory needed is 4,320,000 bytes, or just a bit more than 4MB, which doesn't seem excessive to me.

To capture the screen, I'm using .NET's `Graphics.CopyFromScreen()` function. I don't know how it works, but let's say it uses the same amount of memory as `bmp`, so the biggest amount of memory being used at one point of time in this script *according to a pessimistic estimation* rounds up to 10MB. However, I don't think this changes the root of the problem, and `bmp` is declared before any usage of `CopyFromScreen()` anyway.

---

TL;DR, is there a way I can tell Unity that it should let me allocate tons of memory in my scripts if I want to? Or maybe I'm completely off tracks and the problem lies somewhere else?
All answers are more than welcome!
Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: You shouldn't be using the Bitmap class in Unity. Why do you need that? There is likely a way to do that in Unity...

Comment: I need .NET to capture the screen pixels, so it's only natural to use a .NET image container to retrieve them. `CaptureApplication()` returns a `Bitmap` filled with the screen pixels, and I save it in a memory stream that I read to convert all the pixels to an array of `Unity.Color`, which I then feed to a texture painted on my in-game screen. But that's not relevant to the question, is it?

Comment: Do not use anything that's from the Form API. The point of using Unity is to be able to run in on multiple platforms and mobile devices. What you have now will only work on Windows. If you want to make Windows app only, use WPF or Windows form otherwise use Unity correctly.. `Texture2D.ReadPixels` is used to read screen pixels in Unity.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36186209) for more info

Comment: I think you misunderstood my point. I want a screenshot of a window that is *not* managed by Unity. The way to do this totally depends on your OS, so yes, I'm using the Windows API and .NET to achieve this on Windows. I created a couple utilities using the Windows API and .NET, and it turns out I get the pixels in the `System.Drawing.Bitmap` format. I then read and convert the `Bitmap` to convert it to a `Unity.Color[]` that gets fed to a texture painted on my in-game screen.

Comment: That's fine as long as you understand that you're sacrificing cross-platform compatibility.  Out of curiosity, why do you want to avoid using the Unity way of getting a screenshot?

Comment: Soo.... You're using Unity to capture a screenshot of a program that was not made with Unity? Also, is this something that happens during runtime or are you creating this to speed up your development pipeline?

Comment: @Amy I'm not *avoiding* the Unity way of taking a screenshot, there is just no Unity way that I know of which would allow me to take a screenshot of a Windows program.

Comment: @qreon ahhh, okay.  i missed that part in the comments, but i see it now.  My mind simply glossed over some words.  thanks.

Comment: @BrandonMiller I'm not using Unity to take a screenshot of a program that was not made with Unity. I'm using Unity to make a game. In that game, there is a screen. I want that screen to display the contents of **another Windows program**. In order to capture the pixels of that program, I need to use .NET because I do not know a Unity way to take a screenshot of an external program. Because I'm using .NET function `Graphics.CopyFromScreen()`, I need a .NET container as well to retrieve the pixels. That's why I'm using `System.Drawing.Bitmap`, which I then convert to a `Unity.Texture2D`.

Comment: I don't suppose `ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot` would be helpful?

Comment: @Amy I already looked into that, and unfortunately, no, I can't get any use out of it... `CaptureScreenshot` saves the image on the disk, which would be awfully slow and frankly overkill, and `CaptureScreenshotAsTexture` captures only the pixels of the game view, which I'm not interested in. :(

Comment: Does this happen on the first screenshot? Are there other bitmaps being created? Upon doing a little digging, it seems like this error is caused by improper (or nonexistent) disposal of your Bitmap object.

Comment: @BrandonMiller just tested that, it does happen on the first screenshot. I wrote the `Update()` function of my screen so that a message appears in the debug log on the first update. Instead of appearing once at the beginning, the message floods the log, which means the script is interrupted in the midcourse of the first iteration. See [here](https://i.imgur.com/BpJn1Bh.png)

Comment: @qreon Unfortunately the firewall at work blocks imgur... BUT, if I understood correctly, if the message is flooding the log then that means it is trying to call your function once each frame, which is why it's an error. It should be fired one time and disposed of as soon as possible. Although, since I'm unable to see the screenshot, maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: @BrandonMiller I'm not sure I understand. The `Bitmap` is instantiated statically, so it is disposed of at the end of the `Update()` function. In my case, it's not even instantiated once, how could I dispose of it? This gives me an idea though, I'll declare my `Bitmap` in the `Start()` function and see if it still complains.

Comment: @qreon, Update() is ran once per frame, whether you call a function at the end of it or not it will be called once per frame. Either put your call in a ButtonDown event or, like you said, call it from within a function that is called only once.

Comment: @BrandonMiller I agree, but how does this create a bug with my `Bitmap`? What I'm saying is that the `Bitmap` is declared statically, so it's properly destroyed once it goes out of scope (i.e. when `Update()` returns). There again, my `Bitmap` is not even instantiated once, because the constructor throws. Anyway, I just tried moving the declaration in the `Start()` function and Unity just froze, so I don't think that's the solution neither. :p

Comment: @qreon Bitmap is notorious for throwing ambiguous errors. This is because, deep down, it is calling function from a native C++ library called GDI+, and apparently exception handling wasn't implemented very well. And yes, while I agree with you that it may not be the solution, something else is happening, and I call that progress. In all, you're not overflowing the stack with attempted Bitmap creation (which is probably what threw the original error), but you ARE creating quite a large Bitmap, so I'm assuming it may take some time. Try another pixel format, and maybe smaller dimensions to test.

Comment: @qreon Also, since you're using pure Mono for this, and not the Unity API, you can actually run this operation on it's own thread.

Comment: @BrandonMiller I'll digest all of this info and try to come up with something, thanks for the help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162130/discussion-between-qreon-and-brandon-miller).